# How to perform a MIN value Grouped By Date Measure in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a measure called PERC that basically spits out a percentage.  I am now creating a measure that I can place in the "Y-Axis Start" function for a trend line.  I need this new measure to calculate the MIN of PERC grouped by [MonthYear] (a column in my data).  How do I perform this? I have tried using the GROUPBY function but keep getting errors no matter how much I play with MIN, MINA and MINX...

My brain wants to do this:

```
CALCULATE(
    MIN([PERC], "*Grouped By*"('Data'[MonthYear])
    )
```

Thank you in advance.  I'll be happy to answer any follow up questions for more context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
MinPERCbyMonthYear :=
VAR MyTable =
    SUMMARIZE ( Table1, Table1[MonthYear], "PERCbyMonthYear", [PERC] )
RETURN
    MINX ( MyTable, [PERCbyMonthYear] )
```

replacing `Table1` as required.